# async and async composition in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm confusing about how to use async and async composition especially in asp.net core

**This is case 1:**

This is code in controller

```
    private readonly InfoService _infoService;
    public HomeController(InfoService infoService)
    {
        _infoService = infoService;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //Create a stopwatch for getting excution time  
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var country = _infoService.GetCountry();
        var state = _infoService.GetState();
        var city = _infoService.GetCity(state);
        watch.Stop();
        ViewBag.WatchMilliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        ViewBag.Data = city;
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> About()
    {
        //Create a stopwatch for getting excution time  
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        var country =  _infoService.GetCountryAsync();
        var state =  _infoService.GetStateAsync();
        var city =  _infoService.GetCityAsync();
        var content = await country;
        var count = await state;
        var name = await city;
        watch.Stop();
        ViewBag.WatchMilliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        ViewBag.Data = name;
        return View();
    }
```

This is code in Infoservice

```
    public string GetCountry()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000); //Use - when you want to block the current thread.  
        return "VietNam";
    }
    public async Task<string> GetCountryAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000); //Use - when you want a logical delay without blocking the current thread.  
        return "VietNam";
    }
    public string GetState()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(5000); //Use - when you want to block the current thread.  
        return "the North";
    }
    public async Task<string> GetStateAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(5000); //Use - when you want a logical delay without blocking the current thread.  
        return "the North";
    }
    public string GetCity()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(6000); //Use - when you want to block the current thread.  
        return "HaNoi";
    }
    public async Task<string> GetCityAsync()
    {
        await Task.Delay(6000); //Use - when you want a logical delay without blocking the current thread.  
        return "HaNoi";
    }
```

Run ***Index*** action, it takes **14003 ms**

Run ***About*** action, it takes **6016 ms**

In this case I thinks it run parallel in ***About*** action => Good in Async

**In the case 2**:

I changes little code in ***About*** action

```
  var watch = new Stopwatch();
  watch.Start();
  var country = await _infoService.GetCountryAsync();
  var state = await _infoService.GetStateAsync();
  var city = await _infoService.GetCityAsync();
  watch.Stop();
  ViewBag.WatchMilliseconds = watch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
  return View();
```

The result of this case:

Run ***Index*** action, it takes **14003 ms**

Run ***About*** action, it takes about **> 14008 ms**, it changes any time low or high, usually higher time in ***Index*** action

So what happen in ***About*** action of this case? The difference in two case of ***About*** action

What happen and difference when has multi request/concurrency to ***About*** action in two case

[ I knows that It's not block thread when compare with ***Index*** action ]

**This is case 3:**

How do I use async in ***About*** action when I want to

- get *state* from value of *country* was returned
- get *city* from value of *country, state* was returned

I'm currently use this way:

```
  var country = await _infoService.GetCountryAsync();
  var state = await _infoService.GetStateAsync(country);
  var city = await _infoService.GetCityAsync(country,state);
```

Has something wrong in there? what happen when have multi concurrently request in this case?

[ I'm thinking that It could either has value or not in multi concurrently request]

What's the best way to use async in this case?

Thank you!

Comment: It's pretty clear that one is running in serial, the other in parallel- what is the question?

Comment: [Always a good read](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and [best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

Comment: Thank for response, cause my poor understanding of async specially async in asp.net core, that is miss understand how async run in  multi concurrently request environment. I've got deeper understand with answer of @CodeFuller, and link of MickyD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you write

```
var country = await _infoService.GetCountryAsync();
var state = await _infoService.GetStateAsync();
var city = await _infoService.GetCityAsync();
```

you make your tasks to be awaited. Control flow will not pass to next operator until the task is completed. So in this sense it's very similar to synchronous code:

```
var country = _infoService.GetCountry();
var state = _infoService.GetState();
var city = _infoService.GetCity(state);
```

But with asynchronous versions, if some I/O operation will block further execution, the thread will be returned to thread pool and could be utilized by another operation.

As regards case 3:

You can use [Task.WhenAll()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall(v=vs.110).aspx) to have the tasks run in parallel and wait for all of them to complete:

```
var countryTask =  _infoService.GetCountryAsync();
var stateTask =  _infoService.GetStateAsync();
var cityTask =  _infoService.GetCityAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(new[] { countryTask, stateTask, cityTask });
```

After tasks have completed you could get the result with `Task.Result` property:

```
var country = countryTask.Result;
```

However do not call `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait()` on unfinished task because it blocks the thread and devalue async model.